# Testcafe-redirecting issue

Tags: automated-tests, roles, credentials, e2e-testing, testcafe

We are trying to test a page which at one point redirects the execution to another page for login credentials. After this we need to go back to initial page and continue from where it stopped before redirection.

How can I achieve this?

I tried with roles but this wouldn't keep the data on the initial page and instead reloads the page which then is empty. Also with roles you always go back to same page.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [roles mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/authentication.html#user-roles) is the only built-in way to save and restore cookies/storages. Each role has its role constructor with the initialization function. Cookies and storages are saved only after a role is initialized. It means that you can try to use a role for the first part of your test and save the page state:

```
const role1 = Role(basePage, {
    // do smth
});

const role2 = Role(loginPage, {
    // login
});

test('test', async t => {
    await t.useRole(role1); // state is saved
    await t.useRole(role2); // 
    await t.useRole(role1); // state is restored
})
```

If this approach does not meet your needs, you can try writing some custom logic to save/restore the state. Please follow this link https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2142 to see an example of a custom solution of how to save/restore localStorage via CustomFunctions.

Comment: Hi Alex,
I have tested this approach on some general sites like www.google.com and it worked. However here at work the webpage we are testing requires a login. So when we start the test we are using a specific drift user throughout the test. Before we started using ROLES we actually manually run the step where we are redirected to the login page and that worked well aswell. (so we start tests with testcafe-live, we run them to some step then we continue manually from the step where redirection takes place, and it works).

Comment: However when using ROLES to go to the redirected page we get a LOGIN FAILED message before the actual redirection has taken place. We have seen that as soon the last code row in the role description is executed by TestCafe, when it jumps out from that role definition, we get this LOGIN FAILED. And at that time we have not even clicked the button which will redirect us to the login page.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to solve this? I want to continue be logged in on the default page while I am redirect to the other (login page) and then when I go back to default I want to continue from where I stopped. As I said, by using the ROLES on general pages without login, I see it works but when we are LOGGED IN then things start failing. Not the test itself but the page shows LOGIN FAILED because in some way it detects that we are moving out from the ROLE definition.

Comment: I can mention that I have added this line just before calling the first role "await t.setNativeDialogHandler(() => {})" and that is because otherwise I get an error in the console saying "Error while restoring configuration after Role switch. A native beforeunload dialog was invoked on page..." Use the NativeDialogHandler function to introduce a handler function for native dialogs

Comment: It's difficult to determine the cause of this behavior without test code and a sample project. I would appreciate it if you create a separate issue on GitHub using the following link: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md
Please attach the test code and sample project (or url), which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Hi, 
New post is created "TestCafe - redirecting issue - LOGIN FAILED  #3014". Please check github.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some design considerations worth making in the app itself, perhaps some usage of local or session storage is in order. Testing aside, wouldn't the user also experience this disappearing data if they manually reloaded, for whatever reason?

In my experience with TestCafe, there were instances where I had to do more in each test than I cared to, to workaround similar issues, including times I couldn't use roles and simply cooked up my own reusable login function that I called here and there.

That seems to be one of the limitations with TestCafe in conjunction with testing such functionality (the SPA paradigm, which perhaps this is). It's going to reload pages, but if I remember correctly there was a discussion about it in their issue tracker, so it may be worth browsing there as well if you haven't already.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunatelly the page is alredy in use so some design changes are not possible at the moment.